# Android Theme.NoTitleBar doesnot work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, titlebar

I am have a facebook like sliding menu bar in my app in which the two content and main layout of the app is handled by a Custom layout class.

I want to remove the titlebar of my app

Issue:

Even though I place

> android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar

in my manifest there is a blank space of title bar. Due to which my whole layout is pushed downwards.

I have tried using

> requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

and

> getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

but still the titlebar space is not removed.

This is how the app looks like

[image]

[image]

I think this is caused due to the Custom LinearLayout class which holds the main sliding layout. But I am unable to remove the titlebar space from the custom layout class.
Suggest a better solution.

Custom Layout Class

```
   public class MainLayout extends LinearLayout {
        public MainLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }
        public MainLayout(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        // Overriding LinearLayout core methods
        // layout based on the children
        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

            mainLayoutWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            menuRightMargin = mainLayoutWidth * 10 / 100;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
            super.onAttachedToWindow();
            menu = this.getChildAt(0);
            content = this.getChildAt(1);   
            content.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    return MainLayout.this.onContentTouch(v, event);
                }
            });

@Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        if(changed) {
           LayoutParams contentLayoutParams = (LayoutParams)content.getLayoutParams();
            contentLayoutParams.height = this.getHeight();
            contentLayoutParams.width = this.getWidth(); LayoutParams menuLayoutParams = (LayoutParams)menu.getLayoutParams();
        menuLayoutParams.width = this.getWidth() - menuRightMargin;          
        }

        menu.layout(left, top, right - menuRightMargin, bottom);
        content.layout(left + contentXOffset, top, right + contentXOffset, bottom);

      }
     }
```

Comment: put you custom layout class here

Comment: If your looking in the preview Window it should still show up there. It will only take affect when the Java is run so when you use it on your phone or an emulator.

Comment: @AndreYonadam it appears the same in device and emulator with a blank white space in title bar

Comment: @praveenSharma i will put the custom layout class shortly

Comment: @praveenSharma here is the custom class code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I was able to remove the titlebar space. 
As it turns out, including this tag

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

on application in manifest made the app fullscreen and corrected the issue. But I wanted the status bar to be visible in my app.
So I had to compromise the status bar on the android versions in which the titlebar space was not reduced and let it be same on other versions.
So here is how I resolved it.

in Manifest, I kept the code as it is

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
```

to remove the titlebar in the app

and in the activity which used the custom linear layout I checked the android version and kept the app fullscreen on versions less than and equal to Gingerbread.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) 
{ 
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,   
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

u can specify directly in the manifest file of the activity

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

Comment: I have done this, but it didnot work,it still looks like the one in snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your manifest file

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the android:theme property to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
       <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help you.

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

// Remove notification bar
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `Theme.NoTitleBar` only works when applied to the whole application, not the activity itself. So put it in the application tag (in the manifest):

```
<application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

Then, add any custom style you have to each activity.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In value\style.xml
define name and themes
e.g,

Then goto your androidmainfest.xml
add within activity like..
   android:theme="@style/NoActionBar"