# App crashing when trying to hide the title bar

Tags: android, android-fullscreen

In order to make a full screen app, I've done the following changes to the manifest of a new "blank activity" project:

```
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

The application crashes when running on any device. The changes I've made have been recommended by many posts here in StackOverflow and I couldn't figure out what I've done wrong.

### Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.app"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.app.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you please post your whole AndroidManifest.xml and the logcat?

Comment: crash = stack trace. post it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Theme.NoTitleBar doesnot work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323137/android-theme-notitlebar-doesnot-work)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just do below way:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

extend:

```
    public class SplashScreen extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
            setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
    }
}
```

Its working fine with  API level 7 or higher.

**EDIT:**

Use `AppCompatActivity` because `ActionBarActivity` @deprecated in API 23.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it programmatically like this:(do not need edit your manifest file if you are using this)

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to show your app in full screen use the following code in style.xml file in res-->values-->styles.xml

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"
```

OR ELSE use the Window Manager in programming code of each activity that are mentioned in Android Manifest file as like below...

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: did you clean your project?

Answer (score 0):

Include this in your manifest file. It will work.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Comment: See clearly my answer. Its different from what you are using.

Comment: You are using android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" instead use this android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin you need to post the stacktrace. the crash could be bcoz of a different reason

Answer (score -1):

```
try
        {
            this.getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e){}

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

this worked for me, try this!

Comment: package com.example.casser;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        try
        {
            this.getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e){}

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}